# How to call script maintained in repo during pre-receive

Tags: git, githooks

Suppose I have a unit-test script maintained under my git. I would like to create a pre-receive hook to call this unit-test. However pre-receive should be installed at server side. In my repository, the directory structure looks completely different from my working tree. How could I call that unit-test script?

Thanks

UPDATE:

Basically, the test script needs to run inside a working tree. Currently, my work around is to do a "git clone" in temp directory and reset the HEAD. However, this approach seems not work with higher version of GIT. Because it not allow ref update in [quarantine environment](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-receive-pack#_quarantine_environment). So I am still looking for a vital solution.

Answer (score 1):

To get a command interpreter (such as bash or perl) to interpret a file full of commands, you must first write a file full of commands.

An object inside a Git repository is not a file, it's just an object, identified by hash ID.  More specifically, if some commit with (say) hash ID `$C` (commit) contains some blob object with hash ID `$B` (blob), you must direct Git to *extract* blob `$B` into a plain-text file somewhere in the file system.  You can then direct the command interpreter to interpret the file.

Note that the hash ID `$C` did not appear above.  It only comes into play when you don't *know* the hash ID `$B` of the blob object.  If you *do* know the hash ID of the commit, and *do* know the pathname *within* commit `$C` under which blob object `$B` is named, you can use `$C` plus the path-name to find `$B`:

```
B=$(git rev-parse $C:path/to/file.ext) || ... do something ...
```

The `rev-parse` will print out the hash ID of blob `$B`, or print an error message to stderr and exit nonzero, so that the `||` clause fires.  Note that `$C` can even be a specific branch or tag name to specify the commit identified by that branch or tag:

```
$ git rev-parse refs/tags/v2.18.0:t/test-lib.sh
28315706be709d28c85785e389b381a8617337e3
```

but:

```
$ git rev-parse refs/tags/v2.18.0:t/nonexistent.sh
refs/tags/v2.18.0:t/nonexistent.sh
fatal: Path 't/nonexistent.sh' does not exist in 'refs/tags/v2.18.0'
```

`refs/tags/v2.18.0:t/nonexistent.sh` is the standard output, while `fatal: ...` is the standard error output, so with `B=$(...)` we get:

```
$ B=$(git rev-parse refs/tags/v2.18.0:t/nonexistent.sh)
fatal: Path 't/nonexistent.sh' does not exist in 'refs/tags/v2.18.0'
$ echo $?
128
$ echo $B
refs/tags/v2.18.0:t/nonexistent.sh
```

Instead of, or in addition to, `rev-parse`, you can use `git cat-file -p` to print the *contents* of that blob, by either its raw hash ID or by name:

```
$ B=$(git rev-parse refs/tags/v2.18.0:t/test-lib.sh)
$ git cat-file -p $B | head
# Test framework for git.  See t/README for usage.
#
# Copyright (c) 2005 Junio C Hamano
#
# This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 2 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
```

or:

```
$ git cat-file -p refs/tags/v2.18.0:t/test-lib.sh | head -1
# Test framework for git.  See t/README for usage.
```

If you wish, you can examine the tree of any given commit (such as `$B` or `refs/tags/v2.18.0`) using `git ls-tree`.  Use `-r` to do a recursive listing.  The result can be quite long; here's part of the output for `v2.18.0`:

```
$ git ls-tree -r refs/tags/v2.18.0
...
100644 blob 939d6870ecd7cfbc62f9fa3fb867e5c7362ed9bd    submodule.c
100644 blob 7856b8a0b3d676cde20095f69a4d000d8cf38615    submodule.h
100644 blob 5261e8cf499006c1d84fc42a3e96e4dee7f09ba1    symlinks.c
100644 blob 3bd959ae523cff7fe3a29f1abb92019b6d10515f    t/.gitattributes
100644 blob 4e731dc1e3bef53903f030ee7c63fe7ef7324cb1    t/.gitignore
...
100644 blob ac22ccbd3ee9f03a3b38249ac8efdbe96b5da2cd    t/test-binary-2.png
100644 blob 2b2181dca09089ed36d10ee8f6f67eedda8cf352    t/test-lib-functions.sh
100644 blob 28315706be709d28c85785e389b381a8617337e3    t/test-lib.sh
100755 blob 46bf6184798442560ad3ae7f68a7972680c5f8eb    t/test-terminal.perl
100644 blob d4ae6676d159599468de235bcf10a672cb452592    t/valgrind/.gitignore
100644 blob 0a6724fcc45eed89d612b0e641fd3fe6d4231fcb    t/valgrind/default.supp
100755 blob 669ebaf68be006ee53911f02da72e56cb5a100f0    t/valgrind/valgrind.sh
100644 blob 3d37c1bd251c5f8c5eb06ede72ab57b323888709    tag.c
100644 blob d469534e82a87b651abe752469d0547c2b560e10    tag.h
100644 blob 3467705e9b0e14a0230473186079e83a582e4345    tar.h
100644 blob 139ecd97f8eb88b597aab50c2eb2b171a11ef3ef    tempfile.c
```

This should give you enough building blocks to produce the answer to your own question:

> I would like to create a pre-receive hook to call [a] unit-test.

So, on the server, you need a script.  This script is *separate from* the repository (there's a copy of the script in `.git/hooks/pre-receive`—the receiving repository is typically `--bare` so that it has no work-tree at all, so that the idea of linking to the work-tree copy of the script is a non-starter).

> However pre-receive should be installed at server side.

Correct.

> In my repository, the directory structure looks completely different from my working tree.

This is entirely irrelevant.  The server does not have your work-tree; the server is a Git repository, probably `--bare` and hence with *no* work-tree.

> How could I call that unit-test script?

First, locate the commit or commits you wish to test, probably using the standard input of the pre-receive hook.  The pre-receive hook receives, on its standard input, a list of lines.  Each line has the format:

> ```
> <old-value> SP <new-value> SP <ref-name> LF
> ```

just as is described in [the githooks documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks/#pre-receive).  The `<ref-name>` is always the full reference name, so it has the form `refs/tags/...` when the push is requesting that the server create or update a *tag* name, `refs/heads/...` when the push is requesting that the server create or update a *branch* name, and some other form for any other request.  Remember that one `git push` operation can make multiple requests, so you should scan *each* line for *each* reference update.

Exactly one of the old or new hash value in each line may consist of all-zeros.  This is the special *null hash*.  If the old hash is all-zero, the request is to *create a new reference*.  If the new hash is all-zero, the request is to *delete an existing reference*.  Otherwise the request is to *update an existing reference*.  The old hash comes from your own Git, rather than the requesting Git, so this part is quite trustworthy.

Having read through all the input lines, discovered all the requests, and figured out based on them which commit(s) to test, your job is now to *find* the test(s) you wish to run, and run them.  For each such test, extract it to a real file and run it, however that is to be done in your test framework.

Use the result(s) of your test(s), if any, to inform your pre-receive hook as to whether to allow the receive to proceed or to object to the entire push.  If you object to the push, the whole operation is canceled.

Any messages you produce to stdout or stderr will be related to whomever is doing `git push`, where they will be prefixed by the string `remote:` to indicate that these messages are coming from your code, rather than from Git itself.  Use these strings to tell someone *why* their push is rejected and how to fix it, otherwise you will cause them a lot of confusion.

#### Notes on locating commits to test

Some systems test only the *final* commit that goes on some particular branch or branches.  This is the simpler method since you can just use the new hash ID as your commit.

Other test systems test *every new commit* that goes onto some particular branch or branches.  To do this, use `git rev-list`, which is very much like `git log` except that its output is designed to be read by a computer program.  Instead of printing the log message for each commit, it prints the hash ID of each commit.

Hence, if a push request says, e.g.:

```
0123456789012345678901234567890123456789 aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbccccccccccdddddddddd refs/heads/develop
```

you know that the push is a request to set `refs/heads/develop` to hash ID `aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbccccccccccdddddddddd` when it's currently `0123456789012345678901234567890123456789`.  The commits that will be *newly reachable* via branch name `develop` are therefore exactly those printed by:

```
git rev-list 0123456789012345678901234567890123456789..aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbccccccccccdddddddddd
```

so run that command and gather its output (a list of commit hash IDs) to find the commits to test.

Note that if a push *removes* some commit(s), they will be listed by the reversed operation:

```
git rev-list aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbccccccccccdddddddddd..0123456789012345678901234567890123456789
```

You can use this to detect forced push operations that would strip commits away from a branch.

Comment: Thanks for taking trouble to explain the details. However, the test script basically need the whole working tree to run successfully. My understanding is based on your method we can get scripts content out so that we can run the script. But without the the whole work tree, the script can not run properly in my case. Any more tips?

Comment: You can use `git checkout`, in a post-receive script, to *fill in* a work-tree. However, a bare repository doesn't *have* a work-tree. This produces a dilemma. There are several work-arounds, all of which require a bit deeper knowledge about Git. Your best best at this point is probably a prepackaged CI/CD system like Jenkins or Travis or CircleCI or similar, since those are all built for this kind of thing. (I've used two of these and hate both of them :-) , and have not tried CircleCI myself.)